# Dynamic .so vs so.NUMBER libraries loading on Android/Linux

Tags: android, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I was compiling gstreamer 1.4.4 from source, by using configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi flag to get the ARM .so and .a binaries.
Then I used gst-android 0.10 build tools to link libraries into `gstreamer_android.so`.
That works fine.
The problem is that I don't know how to deploy the `gst-rtsp-server.so` on Android. All the libraries are embedded into .so files  but this one doesn't  depend on gstreamer_andorid.so  but:

```
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgstreamer-1.0.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgio-2.0.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgobject-2.0.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libglib-2.0.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libintl.so.8]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0]
```

(even if I create custom Android.mk and point LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  to gstreamer_android.so)

So I don't know how to either "register" those libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 from gstreamer_android.so or append gstrtspserver.so into gstreamer_android.so. I tried later by adding into gst-android's Android.mk but then I get this error:

```
gst-build-armeabi/gstreamer_android.o:gstreamer_android.c:function gst_android_register_static_plugins: error: undefined reference to 'gst_plugin_rtspserver_register'
```

So I am cleary doing something wrong, can anyone point me to the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a solution,
It was enought to add something like this to gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer-1.0.mk

```
GSTREAMER_RTSP_SERVER_LIBS := -Wl,--whole-archive /path/to/gst-rtsp-server-1.4.4/gst/rtsp-server/.libs/libgstrtspserver-1.0.a
```

and then append this flags to GSTREAMER_ANDROID_LIBS like this:

```
GSTREAMER_ANDROID_LIBS := $(GSTREAMER_RTSP_SERVER_LIBS) $(call fix-deps,-lgiognutls, -lhogweed)
```

If you need a custom Android.mk to build RTSP server here's one to start with

[Android.mk](http://pastebin.com/05Z3ni0s)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand external library versioning. I found [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/chapter5-5.html) helpful.

Second, you need to realize that there may be a reason `libintl.so` is not named `libintl.so.8` -- they are probably not ABI-compatible. Renaming (or creating a symlink) from `libintl.so` to `libintl.so.8` will cause it to be found, but is likely to result in a runtime crash.

Last, the reason you depend on `libintl.so.8` is likely that at link time you are using the wrong `libintl.so` (one that has `SONAME` of `libintl.so.8` instead of `libintl.so`). Did you build this `libintl.so` yourself from gnulib? There may be a different version in the android tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My libraries should be ABI compatible. I tried to post simplified version of my problem: I was cross compiling gstreamer from source, including glib and all other dependencies. Everything looked fine, except I have this error on runtime. Maybe I could use -h option from your link at oracle's doc. If I rename library to match the version I get SIGSEGV and messages like: E/GLib+GLib-GObject(8033): g_param_spec_uint64: assertion 'default_value >= minimum && default_value <= maximum' failed so it looks to me that something is more wrong than just this one..

Comment: Found a solution to my problem: some libraries were linked with x64 version of glib and not the ARM version I wanted them to. I solved this issue by setting GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS env. variables to a configure script call.

Comment: Edited my question to be more clear of what am I trying to do